# Subtract days on a looped date in PHP

Tags: php, date, strtotime

This is my code i loop threw a couple of dates in a while loop where i try to create a startdate variable three days earlier than looped date. This does not work. Please help me! :)

```
<?php
// Start date
$date = '2015-07-01';
// End date
$yesterday = '2015-08-13';

while (strtotime($date) <= strtotime($yesterday)) {
    //the start date
    $startdate = date(strtotime("-3 day", strtotime($date)));

    //the end date
    $enddate = $date;

    echo $startdate . " - " . $enddate . "<br>";
    $date = date ("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($date)));

}
?>
```

Comment: Just to clarify: are you trying to create a list of dates with a period of -3 days all the way back to the start date?

Comment: I know this is probably academic - but isn't the 13th today?

Comment: Yes I am making a list. I edited the code to make it more complete.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```php
$startDate = new DateTime('2015-07-01');
$currentDate = new DateTime('2015-08-13');

$dates = [];

while ($currentDate >= $startDate) {
    $dates[] = clone $currentDate;
    $currentDate->modify('-3 days');
}

print_r($dates);
```

It decrements the current date by three days while it is greater than or equal to the start date in a loop, clones each instance and creates a list going backwards.

This yields:

```
Array
(
    [0] => DateTime Object
        (
            [date] => 2015-08-13 00:00:00.000000
            [timezone_type] => 3
            [timezone] => UTC
        )

    [1] => DateTime Object
        (
            [date] => 2015-08-10 00:00:00.000000
            [timezone_type] => 3
            [timezone] => UTC
        )

    [2] => DateTime Object
        (
            [date] => 2015-08-07 00:00:00.000000
            [timezone_type] => 3
            [timezone] => UTC
        )

    [3] => DateTime Object
        (
            [date] => 2015-08-04 00:00:00.000000
            [timezone_type] => 3
            [timezone] => UTC
        )

    [4] => DateTime Object
        (
            [date] => 2015-08-01 00:00:00.000000
            [timezone_type] => 3
            [timezone] => UTC
        )

    [5] => DateTime Object
        (
            [date] => 2015-07-29 00:00:00.000000
            [timezone_type] => 3
            [timezone] => UTC
        )

    [6] => DateTime Object
        (
            [date] => 2015-07-26 00:00:00.000000
            [timezone_type] => 3
            [timezone] => UTC
        )

    [7] => DateTime Object
        (
            [date] => 2015-07-23 00:00:00.000000
            [timezone_type] => 3
            [timezone] => UTC
        )

    [8] => DateTime Object
        (
            [date] => 2015-07-20 00:00:00.000000
            [timezone_type] => 3
            [timezone] => UTC
        )

    [9] => DateTime Object
        (
            [date] => 2015-07-17 00:00:00.000000
            [timezone_type] => 3
            [timezone] => UTC
        )

    [10] => DateTime Object
        (
            [date] => 2015-07-14 00:00:00.000000
            [timezone_type] => 3
            [timezone] => UTC
        )

    [11] => DateTime Object
        (
            [date] => 2015-07-11 00:00:00.000000
            [timezone_type] => 3
            [timezone] => UTC
        )

    [12] => DateTime Object
        (
            [date] => 2015-07-08 00:00:00.000000
            [timezone_type] => 3
            [timezone] => UTC
        )

    [13] => DateTime Object
        (
            [date] => 2015-07-05 00:00:00.000000
            [timezone_type] => 3
            [timezone] => UTC
        )

    [14] => DateTime Object
        (
            [date] => 2015-07-02 00:00:00.000000
            [timezone_type] => 3
            [timezone] => UTC
        )

)
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I should note that `$dates = [];` is PHP 5.4 array syntax, so if you're using 5.3 just use `$dates = array();` instead.

Answer (score 0):

build a date with date() and mktime():

```
$date = '2015-07-01';
// fill $year,$month and $day with exploded values 
list($year,$month,$day) = explode("-",$date);

// add 3 Days
echo date("Y-m-d",mktime(0,0,0,$month,$day+3,$year));

// 10 Days earlier
echo date("Y-m-d",mktime(0,0,0,$month,$day-10,$year));

// 2 Month earlier
echo date("Y-m-d",mktime(0,0,0,$month-2,$day,$year));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to list dates between `$startDate` and `$endDate`, with 3 days interval each time:

```
$startDate = new Datetime('2015-07-01');
$endDate = new Datetime('2015-08-13');
$interval = new DateInterval('P3D');

while ($startDate->format('Y-m-d') < $endDate->format('Y-m-d')) {
    echo $startDate->format('Y-m-d').'<br />';
    $startDate->add($interval);
}
echo $endDate->format('Y-m-d').'<br />';
```

If you need to do it backwards, just use `sub()` instead of `add()` and invert `$startDate` and `$endDate`.